# number of multiplication steps required to solve Ax = b

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity

If we can factorize $A$ in $LU$,
We can solve $Ax = b$ in 2 steps:

1. Solve $Lc = b$ for c
2. Solve $Ux = c$ for x

As per the Linear algebra book by Gilbert Strang, each step takes $n^2/2$ number of multiplication-subtraction. I am able to find that for 2nd step, but not for the first step. For $Lc = b$, I can see that there are  $(n^2 - n)$ no. of multiplication-subtractions.

Can anyone please help me finding how we have $(n^2/2)$ calculations ?

Thanks.

Comment: Since $n^2-n$ and $n^2/2$ are both $\Theta(n^2)$, you are apparently worrying about the _exact_ number of operations. In that case note that $n^2/2$ is non-integer for odd $n$, so it cannot be the exact number. To answer exactly, you should specify which one of $L,U$ has entries $1$ on the diagonal (which saves out a multiplication) and tell which operations you are counting. And specifying just how you solve those equations will tell you the right numbers easily.

Comment: L has 1's in diagonal. And I am trying to find total number of multiplications and subtractions for solving Lc = b . As per the book, this is solved by forward elimination. I could figure out that, for Ux = c, I need total n(n+1)/2 multiplications and n(n-1)/2 subtractions, so total n^2/2 calculations. But I can't find the same answer for Lc = b .